# Print new line to $mdToast

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I print a new line (`\n`) in $mdToast.

my code:

```
function Notification(text) {
    $mdToast.show(
        $mdToast.simple()
            .textContent(text)
            .action('OK')
            .hideDelay(5000)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML in your template, so just put a `<br/>` tag in there and you're good to go. Check out $mdToast.show docs [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdToast)

Comment: but when using templates with just `$mdToast` and no `$mdToast.simple()`. two way data binding doesn't work. I can't display values of variables attached to the scope

Answer (score 0):

you can do so

```
$mdToast.show({
          hideDelay   : 3000,
          position    : 'top right',
          templateUrl : 'your_template.html'
        });
```

and in your template

```
<div>SomeContent <br> Some Other Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add to your CSS:

```css
.md-toast-text {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

This will interpret `\n` as a new line (as if it was a `<br>`).

Answer (score 0):

For Angular Material 8,
add the following css to the main **style.css** file

```
.mat-snack-bar-container{
    white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```